Uploading to TestFlight using Fastlane
I have been trying to upload my app to TestFlight from GitHub Actions for sometime now with no luck.
Workflow yml file:
name: iOS Build and Upload to TestFlight

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build-ios:
    runs-on: macos-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up Ruby
        uses: ruby/setup-ruby@v1
        with:
          ruby-version: '3.3'

      # Install Bundler and CocoaPods
      - name: Install Bundler and CocoaPods
        run: |
          gem install bundler
          sudo gem install cocoapods

      - name: Install Node.js dependencies
        run: npm install

      - name: Navigate to iOS directory, clean Pods, and remove Podfile.lock
        run: |
          cd ios
          pod deintegrate
          rm -rf Podfile.lock
          pod install --repo-update

      - name: Install Fastlane dependencies
        run: |
          cd ios
          bundle install

      - name: Update OpenSSL
        run: |
           brew install openssl@3
           brew link --force openssl@3
    
      - name: Check OpenSSL Version and Path
        run: |
           which openssl
           openssl version
         
      - name: Decode and set up iOS certificate
        run: |
          echo "${{ secrets.IOS_DISTRIBUTION_CREDENTIALS }}" | base64 --decode > ios_distribution.p12
          echo "${{ secrets.PROVISIONING_PROFILE }}" | base64 --decode > provisioning.mobileprovision
        shell: bash

      - name: Import certificate to keychain
        run: |
          security create-keychain -p "" build.keychain
          security import ios_distribution.p12 -k build.keychain -P "${{ secrets.P12_PASSWORD }}" -T /usr/bin/codesign
          security set-keychain-settings build.keychain
          security unlock-keychain -p "" build.keychain
          security set-key-partition-list -S apple-tool:,apple: -s -k "" build.keychain
          security list-keychains -d user -s build.keychain $(security list-keychains -d user | tr -d '"')
          security list-keychains -s build.keychain
        shell: bash

      - name: Set provisioning profile
        run: |
          mkdir -p ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles
          cp provisioning.mobileprovision ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/
        shell: bash

      - name: Print Current Directory
        run: pwd

      - name: Set Permissions for API JSON File
        run: chmod 600 ios/fastlane/api.json
      
      - name: Build and upload to TestFlight
        run: |
          cd ios
          bundle exec fastlane beta
        env:
     #    APP_STORE_CONNECT_API_KEY_PATH: ios/AuthKey.json
          FASTLANE_USER: ${{ secrets.FASTLANE_USER }}
          FASTLANE_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.FASTLANE_PASSWORD }}

Fastfile:
default_platform(:ios)

platform :ios do
  desc "Push a new beta build to TestFlight"
  lane :beta do
    # Increment build number automatically
    increment_build_number(
      xcodeproj: "somename.xcodeproj"
    )

    Dir.chdir("../") do
      sh "bundle exec pod install"
      sh "npm install"
    end    

    # Build the app using your specific workspace and scheme
    build_app(
      workspace: "somename.xcworkspace",
      scheme: "somenameQA",
      export_method: "app-store",
      export_options: {
        provisioningProfiles: {
          "com.somename.app.qa" => "com.somename.app.qa"
        }
      }
    )  
    
    app_store_connect_api_key(
      path: "fastlane/api.json"
    )

    # Upload the build to TestFlight
    pilot
  end
end

I keep getting the following error:
[13:52:25]: Called from Fastfile at line 29
[13:52:25]: 
[13:52:25]:     27: 
[13:52:25]:     28:     # Upload the build to TestFlight
[13:52:25]:  => 29:     pilot( api_key_path: "fastlane/api.json" )
[13:52:25]:     30:   end
[13:52:25]:     31: end
[13:52:25]:

[13:52:25]: unexpected token at '{
    "key_id": "39BDY8TU5D%9",
    "issuer_id": "2323AAsa-2f53-4853-97fe-fb7d0777b2aa",
    "key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIGHAgSASFDFDdsdgfdgfSM49AwEHBG0wawIBAQQgN3TOiJNOCNVV8nlQ3oqIvYjZgZcKqNul75mZoasdgasdgasdgADSFNeLgKR+3NMEcoZyzC/TCGER6vHEaThF1uFHAmZny4dri+SDJSOdUBkN7jSz0L1gYDKujDIlpQAYNjz+7Srg\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----",
    "duration": 1200, # optional (maximum 1200)
    "in_house": false # optional but may be required if using match/sigh
  }'
+----------------------------------------------+
|               fastlane summary               |
+------+-------------------------+-------------+
| Step | Action                  | Time (in s) |
+------+-------------------------+-------------+
| 1    | default_platform        | 0           |
| 2    | increment_build_number  | 0           |
| 3    | bundle exec pod install | 16          |
| 4    | npm install             | 7           |
| 5    | build_app               | 441         |
|    | pilot                   | 0           |
+------+-------------------------+-------------+
[13:52:25]: fastlane finished with errors
Looking for related GitHub issues on fastlane/fastlane...
bundler: failed to load command: fastlane (/Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.3.6/arm64/bin/fastlane)
/Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.3.6/arm64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/json-2.7.2/lib/json/common.rb:220:in parse': [!] unexpected token at '{ (JSON::ParserError)
    "key_id": "1234123SDADSF",
    "issuer_id": "12341234-2f1234124353-1243-3223-12421342134",
    "key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nsomeprivatekey\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----",
    "duration": 1200, # optional (maximum 1200)
    "in_house": false # optional but may be required if using match/sigh
  }'
    from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.3.6/arm64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/json-2.7.2/lib/json/common.rb:220:in parse'
    from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.3.6/arm64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.225.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/connect_api/token.rb:39:in from_json_file'
    from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.3.6/arm64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.225.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/connect_api/token.rb:34:in from'
    from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.3.6/arm64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.225.0/pilot/lib/pilot/manager.rb:23:in login'
    from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.3.6/arm64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.225.0/pilot/lib/pilot/manager.rb:19:in start'
    from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.3.6/arm64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.225.0/pilot/lib/pilot/build_manager.rb:17:in upload'
    from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.3.6/arm64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.225.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/actions/upload_to_testflight.rb:34:in run'
    from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.3.6/arm64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.225.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:263:in block (2 levels) in execute_action'
    from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.3.6/arm64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.225.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/actions/actions_helper.rb:69:in execute_action'
    from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.3.6/arm64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.225.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:255:in block in execute_action'
    from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.3.6/arm64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.225.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:229:in chdir'
    from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.3.6/arm64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.225.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:229:in execute_action'
    from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.3.6/arm64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.225.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:157:in trigger_action_by_name'
    from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.3.6/arm64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.225.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/fast_file.rb:159:in method_missing'
    from Fastfile:29:in block (2 levels) in parsing_binding'
    from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.3.6/arm64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.225.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/lane.rb:41:in call'
    from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.3.6/arm64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.225.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:49:in block in execute'
    from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.3.6/arm64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.225.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:45:in chdir'
    from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.3.6/arm64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.225.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:45:in execute'
    from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.3.6/arm64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.225.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/lane_manager.rb:46:in cruise_lane'
    from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.3.6/arm64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.225.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/command_line_handler.rb:34:in handle'
    from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.3.6/arm64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.225.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/commands_generator.rb:110:in block (2 levels) in run'
    from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.3.6/arm64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/commander-4.6.0/lib/commander/command.rb:187:in call'
    from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.3.6/arm64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/commander-4.6.0/lib/commander/command.rb:157:in run'
    from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.3.6/arm64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/commander-4.6.0/lib/commander/runner.rb:444:in run_active_command'
    from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.3.6/arm64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.225.0/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/ui/fastlane_runner.rb:124:in run!'
    from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.3.6/arm64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/commander-4.6.0/lib/commander/delegates.rb:18:in run!'
    from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.3.6/arm64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.225.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/commands_generator.rb:363:in run'
    from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.3.6/arm64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.225.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/commands_generator.rb:43:in start'
    from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.3.6/arm64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.225.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/cli_tools_distributor.rb:123:in take_off'
    from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.3.6/arm64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.225.0/bin/fastlane:23:in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.3.6/arm64/bin/fastlane:25:in load'
    from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.3.6/arm64/bin/fastlane:25:in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.3.6/arm64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.18/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:58:in load'
    from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.3.6/arm64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.18/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:58:in kernel_load'
    from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.3.6/arm64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.18/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:23:in run'
    from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.3.6/arm64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.18/lib/bundler/cli.rb:455:in exec'
    from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.3.6/arm64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.18/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:28:in run'
    from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.3.6/arm64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.18/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in invoke_command'
    from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.3.6/arm64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.18/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:527:in dispatch'
    from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.3.6/arm64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.18/lib/bundler/cli.rb:35:in dispatch'
    from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.3.6/arm64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.18/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:584:in start'
    from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.3.6/arm64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.18/lib/bundler/cli.rb:29:in start'
    from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.3.6/arm64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.18/exe/bundle:28:in block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.3.6/arm64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.18/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:117:in with_friendly_errors'
    from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.3.6/arm64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.18/exe/bundle:20:in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.3.6/arm64/bin/bundle:25:in load'
    from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.3.6/arm64/bin/bundle:25:in <main>'
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

I tried hardcoding the key, I tried encoding it to base64, i am stuck.
As per the documentation of Fastlane this should work.
Any help is appreciated!

You have included your pri age key in the question. You should ensure that you now revoke this.  Your json file is invalid. You need to remove the "#" comments. They are in the documentation for information but cannot be in the actual json file.

The keys where changed its not the actual key but thank you for pointing it out! The comments where since removed and I get a different error.
No value found for 'key_id'

You should [ask] a new question showing the error

It looks like you are able to access the app store given that increment_build_number is working. Maybe you can try to using pilot with the username and password instead of the api key.

@AhmadHamze what are the parameters for username and password for pilot?

@root69 You can do this I think:
ENV["FASTLANE_APPLE_APPLICATION_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD"] = "password"
pilot(username: username)

You can maybe try upload_to_testflight instead of pilot.
Note that I am getting a different error using it, but it might work for you.

@AhmadHamze using FASTLANE_APPLE_APPLICATION_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD does not work for me since my apple account has 2FA. In addition upload_to_testflight results in the same error.
Raised a new question. Thanks for your help.

No worries, this might be a Fastlane issue, there is at least one open issue related to credentials, check https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/21109

JSON files cannot have comments in them.
The comments starting with # are just to help you understand the sample. You need to remove them from your file.

As mentioned, this was already removed and not the case, thanks again for trying to help.

This is the answer to the question you asked. If you are now having a different error, you should ask a new question.

Edited my question above to include the new error

Rather than editing a question that has been answered, It would be better to ask a new question. Your original question would probably be of value to others.

got it, will ask a new one and delete my edits
